# Method Illuminate\Routing\Redirector::round does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

This is how my controller looks like :

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class UserController extends Controller
{

public function getDashboard(){
    return view('dashboard');
}


public function getRegistration(){
    return view('pages.registration');
}

public function getLogin(){
    return view('pages.login');
}

    public function registration (Request $request){


        $name = $request['name'];
        $email = $request['email'];
        $password = bcrypt($request['password']);

        $user = new User();
        $user->name = $name;
        $user->email = $email;
        $user->password = $password;
        $user->save();
        return redirect()->route('login');

    }

    public function Login (Request $request){


            if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request['email'], 'password' => $request['password']]))
            {
                return redirect()->round('dashboard');
            }
            else
            {
            return redirect()->route('registration');
            }
}
}
```

This is how my login looks like :

```
<body style="background-image:url({{url('resources/views/img/cloud.jpg')}}">

    <div class="container">
            <div class="row main">

                <div class="main-login main-center">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{route('login')}}">

                        <h2 style="text-align: center;"> Login </h2>
                        <br />
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="cols-sm-10">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email"  placeholder="Enter your Email"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="cols-sm-10">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password"  placeholder="Enter your Password"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block login-button">Login</button>

                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}">


                        <div class="login-register">
                           <p> Don't Have any Account?<a href="{{url ('/registration')}}"><b> Register Here</b></a></p>
                         </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

i got this error : **Method Illuminate\Routing\Redirector::round does not exist.**
as i am new to laravel, so i don't even understand this error, i cannot find any answer related to this. i think i am missing something, but i can't figure it out. if anyone know so please post the answer :)

Comment: I don't know if you copied the code exactly as it is in your controller files, but take a look at this one:

`$request['passwlooks]` you have a missing single quote.

Comment: @nakov sorry, i copy the exact code, don't how it change, i update the code.

Comment: `return redirect()->round('dashboard');` - should be `return redirect()->route('dashboard');` I guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is because you are trying to access a method that does not exists.

So try changing this:

```
return redirect()->round('dashboard');
```

into this:

```
return redirect()->route('dashboard');
```

Comment: OMG how route goes to round :P BTW THANK YOU IT's Solved!

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `redirect()->round('dashboard');` - did you mean `redirect()->route('dashboard');`?

Answer (score 0):

Redirect from controller

i) so try this method:

```
function View(){ 
 $user="hello";
 return redirect('view')->back()->with('user');
}
```

ii) Create route

```
Route::get('view',function($user){
 return $user."world";
 })->name('view');
```